# Impact of changing swappiness at runtime

Tags: 16.04, mysql, aws

On one of my aws ec2 m4.10xlarge instance running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with 160 GB memory, I want to change the swappiness from the default 60 to 10. Does changing this at runtime using

```
sysctl -w vm.swappniess=10
```

have any negative impact when executing this command?

I have a production MySQL 5.7 database running on this instance. So while changing the swappiness will there be any micro stalls or any other issues which I should be considering? Is it safe to run this when the database is busy or does it need to be run only during off-hours?
   Please suggest.

Comment: I don't see why changing this system parameter would negatively affect running processes.

Comment: Thanks vanadium. Does it need machine reboot?

Comment: It is a change at run time.